# Permission denied Django file upload

Tags: django, apache, shell

This may need to migrate to ServerFault, but I am having trouble uploading files to a folder in Django.

It works fine locally but when I upload a file to `/opt/Webapp/userfiles` I get the following:

```
[Thu Oct 23 13:21:32 2014] [error] [client 10.8.1.143] PHP Notice:  Undefined property: a1234_Registrants::$name in /var/www/html/sugarcrm/include/SugarObjects/templates/basic/Basic.php on line 53
[Thu Oct 23 13:21:36 2014] [error] Internal Server Error: /upload/
[Thu Oct 23 13:21:36 2014] [error] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Thu Oct 23 13:21:36 2014] [error]   File "/opt/.virtualenvs/smart/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 111, in get_response
[Thu Oct 23 13:21:36 2014] [error]     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
[Thu Oct 23 13:21:36 2014] [error]   File "/opt/.virtualenvs/smart/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/http.py", line 41, in inner
[Thu Oct 23 13:21:36 2014] [error]     return func(request, *args, **kwargs)
[Thu Oct 23 13:21:36 2014] [error]   File "/opt/Webapp/jobs/views.py", line 55, in upload
[Thu Oct 23 13:21:36 2014] [error]     instance.save()
[Thu Oct 23 13:21:36 2014] [error]   File "/opt/.virtualenvs/smart/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 590, in save
[Thu Oct 23 13:21:36 2014] [error]     force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
[Thu Oct 23 13:21:36 2014] [error]   File "/opt/.virtualenvs/smart/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 618, in save_base
[Thu Oct 23 13:21:36 2014] [error]     updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
[Thu Oct 23 13:21:36 2014] [error]   File "/opt/.virtualenvs/smart/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 699, in _save_table
[Thu Oct 23 13:21:36 2014] [error]     result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
[Thu Oct 23 13:21:36 2014] [error]   File "/opt/.virtualenvs/smart/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 732, in _do_insert
[Thu Oct 23 13:21:36 2014] [error]     using=using, raw=raw)
[Thu Oct 23 13:21:36 2014] [error]   File "/opt/.virtualenvs/smart/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 92, in manager_method
[Thu Oct 23 13:21:36 2014] [error]     return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
[Thu Oct 23 13:21:36 2014] [error]   File "/opt/.virtualenvs/smart/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 921, in _insert
[Thu Oct 23 13:21:36 2014] [error]     return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
[Thu Oct 23 13:21:36 2014] [error]   File "/opt/.virtualenvs/smart/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 919, in execute_sql
[Thu Oct 23 13:21:36 2014] [error]     for sql, params in self.as_sql():
[Thu Oct 23 13:21:36 2014] [error]   File "/opt/.virtualenvs/smart/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 877, in as_sql
[Thu Oct 23 13:21:36 2014] [error]     for obj in self.query.objs
[Thu Oct 23 13:21:36 2014] [error]   File "/opt/.virtualenvs/smart/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py", line 301, in pre_save
[Thu Oct 23 13:21:36 2014] [error]     file.save(file.name, file, save=False)
[Thu Oct 23 13:21:36 2014] [error]   File "/opt/.virtualenvs/smart/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py", line 89, in save
[Thu Oct 23 13:21:36 2014] [error]     self.name = self.storage.save(name, content)
[Thu Oct 23 13:21:36 2014] [error]   File "/opt/.virtualenvs/smart/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 51, in save
[Thu Oct 23 13:21:36 2014] [error]     name = self._save(name, content)
[Thu Oct 23 13:21:36 2014] [error]   File "/opt/.virtualenvs/smart/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 219, in _save
[Thu Oct 23 13:21:36 2014] [error]     fd = os.open(full_path, flags, 0o666)
[Thu Oct 23 13:21:36 2014] [error] OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/opt/Webapp/userfiles/Chrysanthemum.jpg'
```

The permissions of the folder look like this:

```
drwxrwxrwx.  2 apache root   4096 Oct 20 14:22 userfiles
```

I am wondering if the permissions on the source files need to be changed to? Or maybe the group permissions?

Please add any extra tags to this question you see fit, as I am not sure I covered them all.

Comment: I think that location has some restrictions on it. Uploading to /var/www seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing to `/opt/` was as far as I could go, before I was refused. Any folder inside `/opt/` had permissions on it.

I resorted to saving my files in `/var/www/` which seemed more suited.